# Query running but, view not getting created

Tags: oracle, view, sql-grant

I am new to Oracle. I am able to execute:

```
SELECT X, Y, Z. 
FROM SCH2.TAB_A A JOIN SCH2.TAB_B B ON A.CODE = B.CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCH2.MY_V MV ON MV.CODE = B.CODE
WHERE  MV.STATUS = 'A';
```

But when I am trying to put this SELECT statement in a view, I am getting error:

**ORA-00942: table or view does not exist**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW SCH1.NEW_V AS
SELECT X, Y, Z. 
FROM SCH2.TAB_A A JOIN SCH2.TAB_B B ON A.CODE = B.CODE
LEFT OUTER JOIN SCH2.MY_V MV ON MV.CODE = B.CODE
WHERE  MV.STATUS = 'A';
/
```

Tried google,

[SQL Error: ORA-00942 table or view does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16129912/sql-error-ora-00942-table-or-view-does-not-exist)

http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00942.php

But still not able to resolve. If I am able to run the query, why am I getting error when I am trying to put that in a View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This helped

[Oracle Create View issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4082310/oracle-create-view-issue?rq=1)

```
GRANT SELECT ON SCH2.TAB_A TO SCH1;

GRANT SELECT ON SCH2.TAB_B TO SCH1

GRANT SELECT ON SCH2.MY_V TO SCH1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Check that you have direct access privileges, not through a role:

```
SQL> create user sch1 identified by sch1;

SQL> create role scott_acc;

SQL> grant select on scott.emp to scott_acc;

SQL> grant scott_acc to sch1;

SQL> create or replace view sch1.v_1
  2  as select * from scott.emp;
as select * from scott.emp
                       *
error in line 2:
ORA-00942: table or view does npt exist


SQL> grant select on scott.emp to sch1;


SQL> create or replace view sch1.v_1
  2  as select * from scott.emp;

View created.
```